# Outlook Advanced Find Exclude Folder Option

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, gmail, imap

I am using the find all unread email search in outlook for my Google Apps email accounts.

I noticed that outlook will show messages in pairs of 2, one for the unread imap "inbox" and one for the imap "[gmail]/All Mail" inbox.

It is a minor annoyance, however I would still like to exclude the "inbox" folder from the search so that I do not have to view duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer.

```
Go to home
press ctl+e
click on unread (in the Refine section of ribbon)
click on more (in the Refine section of ribbon)
click on In Folder in the more dropdown
Type "All Mail" without quotes (This narrows is down to just the All Mail folder)
```

This is great for viewing all imap unread email in outlook if you have multiple imap accounts.